# How can I combine an input change function with a document ready function?

Tags: jquery

I have some action that should happen on

```
$('input').change(function () {
...
}
```

but also on

```
$( document).ready(function() {
 ...
});
```

is it possible to combine these functions to one like

```
$( document).ready  || $('input').change(function() {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the logic of the handlers to their own function and then call that under both events, something like this:

```
function myFunc() {
    console.log('do something useful here...');
}

$(function() {
    myFunc(); // on load
    $('input').change(myFunc); // on input change
});
```

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

First, create the function that does the thing you need it to do:

```
var doSomething = function() {
    //...
};
```

Then just add that to the event handlers.  Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(doSomething);
$('input').change(doSomething);
```

Or, if the latter needs to also happen in the `ready` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    doSomething();
    $('input').change(doSomething);
});
```

This overall separation of concerns will help organize the code in general anyway.  Keeping your logical operations (`doSomething`) separate from your UI binding (event handlers).